# Is there any way to connect Oracle DBLink with SQL Server AAG Read Intent (Read Only)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink, alwayson

There are two database server, the first using oracle database and the second using SQL Server database.

We are created Database Link (DBLink) from oracle to SQL Server to read the data for reporting purpose, and the SQL Server using replication to replicate data from Principal database.

Now we have planning to using AAG for HA, and planning to change replication into Read Only database (AAG Feature).

Is there possible using DBLink to connect to AAG SQL Server Database using Read Intent ?

Comment: Do not cross post! http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146804/is-there-any-way-to-connect-oracle-dblink-with-sql-server-aag-read-intent-read

Comment: So, should i drop this post ?